# Географическая карта с маршрутом движения в WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, карты

Добрый день, есть ПО созданное в Win Forms, в нем создаются маршруты\рейсы, в БД хранится информация о точка прохождения и их координаты, например:

```
название точки| x | y
---------------------
Склад         | x | y
магазин1      | x | y
магазин2      | x | y
Склад         | x | y
```

Мне нужно выводить на карту маршрут, с помощью чего можно это сделать? Я смотрел в сторону Google Maps Distance Matrix API, но я так понял это штука платная? Может кто сталкивался подскажет как реализовать?

Comment: а каким образом будет складываться маршрут, по порядку следования точек в таблице или же будет алгоритм просчета оптимального маршрута (например ситуация доставки со склада в несколько магазинов)?

Comment: Существует таблица в БД там есть все расстояние между всеми существующими точками, программа оптимизирует маршрут согласно этих расстояний, карта нужна для визуализации.

Comment: @YuriiManziuk У вас нет идей что мне может помочь?

Comment: просчетами оптимального маршрута должен заниматься или очень умный алгоритм, который учитывает много параметров: физическое расстояние между точками или расстояние по дорогам и тдтп. и скорее всего надо будет писать нейронную сеть для выбора оптимального маршрута